# With React what is the best way to handle conditional classes

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, declarative-programming

I have many elements on a component who needs "active" and "disabled" classes on certain conditions.

for example-:
1-There i need to toggle active class on click:-

```
<div className="action-group cont-align">
                        <label>Alignment</label>
                        <div className="action-group-inner">
                            <i className="fas fa-align-left" data-align="Left" onClick={this.handleAlign}></i>
                            <i className="fas fa-align-center" data-align="Middle" onClick={this.handleAlign}></i>
                            <i className="fas fa-align-right" data-align="Right" onClick={this.handleAlign}></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

2-There also i need to toggle active class:-

```
                    <div className="action-group cont-color">
                        <label>Color</label>
                        <div className="action-group-inner">
                            <i className="color-cont black" onClick={this.handleFontColor} data-color="black"></i>
                            <i className="color-cont blue" onClick={this.handleFontColor} data-color="#2027aa"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

3- There i need to add disable class on font-small (when font is too small) and on font-large (when font is too large):-

```
                    <div className="action-group cont-fontSize">
                        <label>Size</label>
                        <div className="action-group-inner">
                            <i className="font-small" onClick={this.handleFontSizeDec}>A</i>
                            <i className="font-large" onClick={this.handleFontSizeInc}>A</i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Do i need to maintain many states just for addition/removal of classes?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use this package: https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames

An example with button's state:

```
var classNames = require('classnames');

var Button = React.createClass({
  // ...
  render () {
    var btnClass = classNames({
      btn: true,
      'btn-pressed': this.state.isPressed,
      'btn-over': !this.state.isPressed && this.state.isHovered
    });
    return <button className={btnClass}>{this.props.label}</button>;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moving the `<i className="fas fa-align-left" data-align="Left" onClick={this.handleAlign}></i>` into a **seperate component** and have **state** hold this and then map through that **state** to render this.

```
this.state ={
 Alignments:[], // Please add all your allingments here
 Colors:[], // Please add all your Color here
 Sizes:[], // Please add all your Size here
 activeAlingment:0,
 activeColor:0,
 activeSize:0
}

handleSetActiveAllingment  = (index) =>{
  this.setState({activeAlingment:index})
}

handleSetActiveColor  = (index) =>{
  this.setState({activeColor:index})
}

handleSetActiveSize  = (index) =>{
  this.setState({activeSize:index})
}
```

Please use this state to map through this **state** to create the Components.

```
this.state.Alignments.map((alingment,Index)=>{
 isactive = this.state.activeAlingment == Index ? "active" : "";
 return <Alingment activeClass={isactive} clickHandler={() => this.handleSetActiveAllingment(Index)}>
});

this.state.Colors.map((color,Index)=>{
 isactive = this.state.activeColor == Index ? "active" : "";
 return <Colors activeClass={isactive} clickHandler={()=>this.handleSetActiveColor(Index)}>
});
```

This way your components will be **reusable** and you will also achieve what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use below snippets and string interpolation to do the work:

```
const classnames = someCondition? "color-cont black": "color-cont black newStyle others";
<div className=`$(classnames)` ...>
```